# Realm, should primaryKey be between indexedProperties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, realm

Do i need to add the primaryKey between the indexedProperties, or is this not necessary and the primaryKey is added by default, or handled differently

```
@implementation User

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"userID";
}

+ (NSArray *)indexedProperties {
    return @[@"userID"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary key is automatically indexed regardless of whether or not you explicitly ask for it to be.